# how to pass a variable to sed from within r

Tags: r, sed

I have a filename Im using to do stuff with; it is a variable representing the path Im interested in. At the end of the script I would like to do some sed cleanup on it but I dont know how to pass the variable to it. Here's what I have:

```
library(gdata)
filename = file.choose()
mydata = read.xls(file.choose())
newdata <- subset(mydata[1:3])
filename=paste(filename,".bed")
write.table(newdata,filename,sep="\t",row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
system("sed -i '' 's/\"//g'" filename)
```

but I get the error as follows-

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "system("sed -i '' 's/\"//g'" filename"
```

Im sure its do do with some kind of "" lunacy but can't figure it out

Comment: Maybe a `,` is missing: `system("sed -i '' 's/\"//g'", filename)`.

Comment: Nope. This gives me the error as follows.......Error in system("sed -i '' 's/\"//g'", filename) : 
  'intern' must be TRUE or FALSE

Comment: and if I set intern=TRUE, then it says  Error in system("sed -i '' 's/\"//g'", filename, intern = TRUE) : 
  'ignore.stdout' must be TRUE or FALSE and if I set this it asks about ignore.sterr and then wait=TRUE or FALSE and so on

Comment: try this `system("sed -i '' 's/\\"//g'" filename)`

Comment: I get this Error: unexpected '/' in "system("sed -i '' 's/\\"//"

Comment: try `system("sed -i '' 's~\\"~~g'" filename)` , is that the double quotes around sed necessary?

Comment: R just gives me a + sign meaning its waiting for more input. The system command does need the double quotes. I tried without and I get the error .....Error: unexpected string constant in:
"system("sed -i '' 's~\\"~~g'" filename)
system(sed -i '"

Comment: `system` expects a character input, which in R means you must wrap it in `"` or `'`. Your problem boils down to how to create a character string that contains both `'` and `"`. (I don't know how to achieve that or if it's even possible.) Also note that \ needs to be escaped with \.

Comment: what about someting like `system("sed -i '' \"s/$( echo "\042" )//g\"" filename)` due to shell interpretation

Comment: Hi NeronLeVelu. This solution gives me the error Error: unexpected input in "system("sed -i '' \"s/$( echo "\"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using paste:

```
system(paste("sed -i '' 's/\"//g'",filename))
```

Also, you might want to use `paste0` instead of `paste` (or add the `sep=""` argument) when you add the extension to `filename`, right now it adds a space between the filename and extension.

```
filename=paste0(filename,".bed")
```

Comment: OK sorted. Thanks NiCE. Also thanks for introducing me to paste0 my next question was how do I get rid of that space. Cheers